# No puedo hacer que mi pagina cambie de imagen de fondo automaticamente

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagen

Estoy intentando que mi pagina cambie de imagen de fondo cada cierto tiempo (10 segundos por ejemplo) pero no ha funcionado, este es el codigo:

```js
var images = new Array(
  'Space.gif',
  'Windows.gif',

);

var slider = setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('body')[0].setAttribute('style', 'background-image: url("'+images[0]+'")');
  images.splice(images.length, 0, images[0]);
  images.splice(0, 1);
}, 10000);
```

```css
body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<script src="screen.js"></script>
```

tambien intenté con este codigo de javascript

```
 function changeBg(){

  const images = [
     'url("Space.gif")',
     'url("Windows.gif")',
    ]
    const selection = document.querySelector('selection')
    const bg = images[Math.floor(Math.random()* images.length)];
    selection.style.backgroundImage = bg; 
}          
setInterval(changeBg, 1000000)
```

Pero tampoco funciona, que puede ser? Me ha faltado escribir algo? Hay algun error de sintaxis? Ayuda porfa!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te adjunto un ejemplo funcional de como lo puedes hacer. Solo coloca en el arreglo `images` todas las imágenes que requieras.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2015/04/10/658869/0c513a3aa2b573851ed2246d547ba00e-700.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: background-image 2s;
}
```

```html
<script>
  var images = [
    'https://www.teahub.io/photos/full/17-174019_small-size.jpg',
    'https://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2015/04/10/658869/0c513a3aa2b573851ed2246d547ba00e-700.jpg'
  ]
  setInterval(function() {
    const image = images.shift()
    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundImage = `url(${image})`
    images.push(image)
  }, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! Puse tu codigo pero solo aparece una de las imagenes, sin embargo aparece de manera perfecta! Con respecto al background-image que publicaste es para un solo archivo, asi que yo hice esto para que fueran de los 2 archivos: background-image: url(Space.gif),url(Windows.gif); Asi se puede? O tiene que ser de otra forma? O Asi como lo escibiste funciona aun asi para cambiar de imagen? Saludos!

Comment: ¿Lo ejecutaste desde acá mismo? ¿No puedes ver como cambia? Pega el código en tu html.

Comment: Ahora si!!!! Lo que pasó fue que accidentalmente le quité un ' a el codigo de Javascript ademas de que los 2 archivos eran exactamente la misma imagen, pero ahora lo corregí y funciona! (aunque por alguna razon ralentizó el PC pero creo que eso es ya otra cosa) pero solo en un html que tengo como pruebas, el html principal sigue sin cambiar imagenes pero creo que eso ya es algun error del HTML. Abriré un hilo aparte sobre esto. Pero mil, mil gracias :) Ya se solucionó este problema!

Answer (score 0):

Quizás la ruta designada no es correcta. Si ese código está en el mismo directorio que los gifs prueba a modificar las rutas con :

```
const images = [
 'url("./Space.gif")',
 'url("./Windows.gif")',
]
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, este codigo tambien es valido si la pagina está en el discoduro de mi PC? No la he subido

Comment: Si, otra cosa, míra que el timeout está mal en el segundo código, si quieres que sea cada 10 segundos debe ser 10000

Comment: Para comprobar que funciona prueba unas rutas a otras webs. por ejemplo placekitten. Prueba en la url con esta url, http://placekitten.com/200/300